# What does return exactly do in a boolean method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, if-statement

In this code:

```
public static void main(String []args){
   int [] a = {10, 20, 30};
   if(m1(a))
     m2(a, 0);
   else
     m2(a, 1);
   for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
     System.out.println(a[i] + " ");
}

public static boolean m1(int [] a){
   return a[0] == a[1] / 2;
}

public static void m2(int [] a, int b){
    a[b] = 1;
}
}
```

in `m2`, what does the line comes after `return` , which is `a[0] == a[1] / 2` do? 
is it a chick statement ? because it is bet confusing when it comes after `return`

Comment: `chick statement`? what is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it in terms of an `if` statement - what does the following do?

```
if (a[0] == (a[1] / 2)) {
...
```

It's a boolean result of an evaluation - `true` or `false`. If it's true, do something.

Using it with `return` returns that boolean result to the caller.

Comment: Yes, now I see, so it will return a boolean expression not an update for the values.. right? Thank you

Comment: You got it. `==` is testing equality, you get the boolean result.

Answer (score 5):

I think you mean m1.

Anyway, it helps if you read the code like this:

```
public static boolean m1(int [] a){
   return (a[0] == (a[1] / 2));
}
```

Take note of operator precedence: parenthesis are evaluated before equality.  That is, return the equality between a[0] and the result of the expression (a[1] / 2).

If you don't know your precedence rules, you could alternatively read the code as:

```
public static boolean m1(int [] a){
    int i = a[1] / 2;
    boolean foo = (a[0] == i);
    return foo;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
return a[0] == a[1] / 2
```

returns true if the expression is actually true, ie. a[0] is equal to a[1] divided by 2, and false otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

That's a boolean expression stating the value that the method will return.
It's no different from a method that returns an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a certain kind of programmers who would rather code this as follows:

```
if( a[0] == a[1] / 2 )
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

We scorn at this kind of programmers, and during lunch break we do not sit anywhere near them.

So, to answer your question, `return a[0] == a[1] / 2;` is a perfectly valid statement, and any experienced programmer would rather see it like this rather than in any other way. The '==' inside the expression tells us that this expression is evaluating to a boolean value, and then this boolean value is returned by the function. That's absolutely fine.

If it would help you to better understand it, you could express it as `return a[0] == (a[1] / 2);` but if you know your operator precedence it is unnecessary, and in any case the alternative (`return (a[0] == a[1]) / 2;`) could not possibly work because the division operator is not applicable to boolean values.

Answer (score 0):

In a method that returns a value, the `return` statement indicates what value to return. For example, this method:

```
public static int timesTwo(int i)
{
    return 2 * i;
}
```

returns two times its argument; so this method:

```
public static void main(String... args)
{
    System.out.println(timesTwo(7)); // prints 14.
}
```

prints `14`.

Your example:

```
public static boolean m1(int [] a)
{
    return a[0] == a[1] / 2;
}
```

returns `true` if `a[0] == a[1] / 2`; otherwise, it returns `false`.

Comment: Nice explanation, now I see.. so it is all about a boolean expression